# Swift Switch Default case that will never be executed

Tags: swift, unit-testing, switch-statement

So, this is a bit of a nitpick about Swift, as I am trying to reach 100% code coverage in my tests, but Swift requires a line of code that will never be reached *by design*.

The offending code:

```
func calculateWorkingOffset(_ offset: Int) -> Int {
    let translatedOffset = abs(offset) % 7
    switch translatedOffset {
    case 0:
        return [appropriate_integer]
    case 1:
        return [appropriate_integer]
    case 2:
        return [appropriate_integer]
    case 3:
        return [appropriate_integer]
    case 4:
        return [appropriate_integer]
    case 5:
        return [appropriate_integer]
    case 6:
        return [appropriate_integer]
    default:
        fatalError("Should never be executed")
    }
}
```

The default case must be present because the Swift compiler requires a case for every potential value of the type (in this case, Int), but there is no way to write a test against the default case.

What's the best thing to do in this case to get full unit test coverage?

Comment: I'm curious how many gory workarounds you'll be willing to implement in the pursuit of 100% test coverage before you come to terms with how counter productive it is

Comment: There was a suggestion for a `switch!` statement which has an *implicit* `default: fatalError()`, see https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20161003/027563.html. As I understand it, this was not generally approved.

Comment: Looking at your example above, you map an integer in the range `0..<7` to a calculation (or even fix-return?) based on the value of the integer in `0..<7`. In case this isn't just an example to cover the question of unreachable code, you might want to refactor this function in something that is briefer but still holds the same semantic value. (How are the `appropriate integer`:s calculated?)

Comment: Alexander: There comes a point where, yes, full coverage is unnecessary, but in this case, it's uncovered a situation where it's possible that there are other ways to write the code, as others are suggesting.

Note also, that this question is a nitpick about the Swift compiler that does a lot of other intuitive things, but doesn't understand in this case that the value in the switch is mapped to a certain range. The default case will never happen, so why should I need to write it? This opens up a whole other set of questions. Should the compiler be able to pick this up? Will it ever? Etc...

Answer (score 3):

This is the best solution I can think of:

```
func calculateWorkingOffset(_ offset: Int) -> Int {
    switch Offset(rawValue: abs(offset) % 7)! {
    case .zero:
        return [appropriate_integer]
    case .one:
        return [appropriate_integer]
    case .two:
        return [appropriate_integer]
    case .three:
        return [appropriate_integer]
    case .four:
        return [appropriate_integer]
    case .five:
        return [appropriate_integer]
    case .six:
        return [appropriate_integer]
    }
}

// Please name this enum and its values appropriately. I called it
// Offset because I have no context of what you're doing
enum Offset: Int {
    case zero
    case one
    case two
    case three
    case four
    case five
    case six
}
```

Although this solves the 100% test coverage problem. It has a lot of drawbacks. When you want to add a new case `.seven`, you have to add a new case in the enum and also the switch statement.